# Could a Moon have its own "Rings", like Saturn's, without the Host Planet having them?

Tags: planets, moons, planetary-rings

I'm currently fleshing out a sci-fi universe and always looking for fun new locales to populate it with, and I saw this phenomenon in a video game I've been playing recently, and it made me curious... the world on which the story takes place appears to be Earth-Like (albeit the setting is a fantasy one), but when you look at the moon, it seems to have very faint "rings" made of dust or particulate, like Saturn's; however, as far as I can tell, the actual main PLANET doesn't have rings of its own?

While I'm not certain that an Earth-Like planet with an Earth-Like Moon would have the right kind of gravity or positioning for this to occur, I was wondering what sort of planet/moon arrangement *might* be able to cause a Moon with Rings. Is it even possible? Or would the host planet's larger gravity well prevent the moon from gathering enough stuff in its orbit for visible rings to form? (The planet doesn't need to be habitable by humans or anything, I just want to know if this effect could be plausibly caused ANYWHERE, by ANY means, or if this was just a touch of whimsy on the game developer's part XD).

Answer (score 6):

Saturn’s moon Rhea [may have rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rings_of_Rhea), and while it’s not been confirmed, the fact that astronomers are considering it shows that they believe it’s possible for a moon to have rings.

Comment: Ooooh, exciting! This gives me all sorts of new questions, but I'll put those in a separate thread once I've developed them a bit... Thank you! :3

Comment: But Saturn has rings. Maybe these (larger and fewer in number) moons sucked their planet's rings dry and what's left only shows up on infrared like Jupiter's rings.